# How to render Laravel tags inside html stored in s3

Tags: laravel, laravel-views

Good day to all.

As the question title says, I do have HTML template code stored in s3 with Laravel tags on it, lets say:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ $landing->title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
@foreach($landing->products as $product)
    <p>{{ $product->title }}</p>
@endforeach
</body>
</html>
```

Then I would like to render this as post-processed html with the Laravel tags replaced as if it were a normal blade template.

In my controller I do have this:

```
print_r( view('render', compact('template', 'landing'))->render() );
```

(I don't want to show in it the browser, just get the html code)

And in the `render.blade.php` I have:

```
{!! html_entity_decode($template->html()) !!}
```

But this will show me the code with the Laravel tags without proper replacement.

Any lights on this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show a sample of the stored HTML?

Comment: Hello @Michael there may be any kind of html code. as an example is the first code block, A html containing laravel tags on it.

Comment: I think you need to update your question with a specific sample of HTML that fails for people to help you out. You are asking a question about the output but not telling us what the input is. Without knowing anything about the input I’m inclined to say the problem lies there. The input isn’t what you think it is.

Comment: I think you're looking for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891398/is-there-any-way-to-compile-a-blade-template-from-a-string)

Comment: This is one of those problems that seems like it should be simple, but due to the way blade files are processed it is damn hard! This question deserves some upvotes. I will work on a solution. In the mean time, you can look at: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-compile-a-blade-template-from-any-folder-other-than-resourcesviews https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079369/is-that-possible-to-use-laravel-blade-outside-the-view-folder and https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/passing-a-variable-into-blade-directive-doesnt-pass-variable-content-but-name-of-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible solutions to this problem.

1. Compile the blade yourself (Not Optimal IMO)

You can make a helper function that will compile blade for you, given a string. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079369/is-that-possible-to-use-laravel-blade-outside-the-view-folder))

helpers.php (Or wherever you want to locate the function)

```
function compile_blade($markup, $data = []) {
    $fs = new \Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
    $b = new \Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler($fs, __DIR__);
    $src = $b->compileString($markup);

    $isPhp = false;
    if (substr( $src, 0, 5 ) === "<?php")
    {
        $isPhp = true;
        $src = substr($src, 5);
    }
    
    $tempFileName = tempnam("/tmp", "blade-compile");
    file_put_contents($tempFileName, $src);

    ob_start();

    extract($data);

    include $tempFileName;
    $out = ob_get_clean();
    if ($isPhp)
    {
        $out = '<?php'.$out;
    }
    
    return $out;
}
```

Then in your controller, you would pre-process the s3 blade for consumption in your render.blade.php file like:

```
    return view('render', [
        'template' => compile_blade($template, $landing),
        'landing' => $landing,
    ));
```

I don't think this is the optimal solution since you end up creating files anyways.

2. Create a new namespace for blade/html coming from s3.

Firstly you need to create a folder in your project like `./storage/local/blade`. Then you need to add a namespace for views in that folder like so:

AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    ...

    view()->addNamespace('s3', storage_path('/local/views');
    ...
}
```

Now to handle retrieving the markup from s3 (in your controller, or elsewhere) you would do something like:

```
    // Lets say the file on s3 is markup.blade.php
    $contents = Storage::disk('s3')->get('path/to/markup.blade.php')
    Storage::disk('local')->put(storage_path('local/views/markup.blade.php'), $contents);
```

Now, if your render.blade.php is being used solely to render the markup on s3, you should just use the new namespaced view instead. You can use this in your controller like:

```
    return view('s3::markup', compact('landing'));
```

It becomes a bit more tricky if you want to use the s3 markup in one of your other blade files. But can be done by extending blade as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27990327/1978311).

```
Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler)
{
    $pattern = $compiler->createMatcher('includeNamespaced');

    $viewPath = realpath($compiler->getPath());
    $parts = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $viewPath);
    $viewsDirectoryIndex = array_search('views', $parts);
    $namespace = $parts[$viewsDirectoryIndex + 1];

    $php = '$1<?php ';
    $php .= 'if($__env->exists(\''.$namespace.'.\'.$2)){';
    $php .= 'echo $__env->make(\''.$namespace.'.\'.$2)->render();';
    $php .= '}';
    $php .= 'else {';
    $php .= 'echo $__env->make($2)->render();';
    $php .= '}';
    $php .= '?>';

    return preg_replace($pattern, $php, $view);
});
```

Now you would be able to @include a namespaced view in your blade files like:

```
    @includeNamespaced('s3/markup')
```

The other reason I prefer solution 2, is that you can get some "caching" effect, if you look to see if the file already exists in local/views, before downloading from s3. Then you can create a scheduled job that deletes files in storage/local/views older than some time limit.

Comment: Looks like the 2nd option is the way to go. thanks!